# Debugging when all threads are waiting (parking)

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

```
ScheduledExecutorService pool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(
        new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("request-data-collector-%d").build());
Runnable requestDataCollector = new RequestDataCollector(sessionIdToRequestData, sessionTimeoutMillis, filePath);
pool.scheduleAtFixedRate(requestDataCollector, 0, 7, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

genericKafkaConsumer.startConsumerServer(new SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper(sessionIdToRequestData, sessionTimeoutMillis, filePath));
```

This is my main part of `Kafka Consumer` program.

Inside `startConsumerServer()`, it uses `ExecutorService` to submit `SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper`:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        for (final KafkaStream<?, ?> stream : streams) {
            runnableClass.setStream(stream);
            executor.submit(runnableClass); //here
        }
        if (!this.executor.isTerminated()) {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    if (this.executor != null) {
        this.executor.shutdown();
    }
    ...
```

I didn't write this part, but I guess this is a standard idiom for running a `Kafka Consumer`.

It processes a stream of messages from `Apache Kafka` by running two programs on different threads, both of which access a `HashMap` of ids to buffers, `sessionIdToRequestData`.

The definition of this map follows:

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentSkipListSet<RequestData>> sessionIdToRequestData = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

This is defined as global, and passed upon construction of the two programs, `RequestDataCollector`, and `SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper`.

They are both `Runnable`s. To briefly describe what they do:

- `SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper` creates a session for a series of request data from when a user first makes a request until the user is inactive for a certain span of time, `TimeoutMillis`.

  The series of data is stored in a buffer in the `HashMap` with `userId` as the key, until the next request from the same user is made after timeout, at which point the buffer is flushed and the data is written to a file.
- `RequestDataCollector` periodically checks the buffers (by iterating the `HashMap`), and if the lastly added data in a buffer has timed out, it flushes the buffer and writes its data to a file.

My problem is that both programs, that work fine when run separately, appear to keep waiting.

As you can see in the screenshot below, all of `kafka-consumer-group` threads, which are in thread pool that runs `SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper`, and `request-data-collector` threads, running `RequestDataCollector`, are in brown color, which means they are `parking` (java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)).

[image]

Looking at the `println` outputs, I guessed `RequestDataCollector` thread was dominating and not releasing locks, because when I ran the program, only the strings I put in the beginning and the end of `RequestDataCollector` were being printed. However, it came as a surprise that even the `RequestDataCollector` thread was waiting (parking) (why was it printing the strings from `RequestDataCollector`? it still puzzles me.)

I have little experience in multithreading, and I read up on debugging on multithreading and tried debugging this on my own, but I feel this is not something I could do in a short time without some help.

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on, or at least direct me to the right direction?

---

Just in case it's needed, I attach the source codes of my programs.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wq2tn1stfimgqq0/AADFAZA9N65RSWme0c8aTA0va?dl=0

and here's a thread dump (Note that the output in thread dumps was nondeterministic and varied. I've seen 2~3 variations and this is only one of them):

```
2016-02-23 12:48:36
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode):

"RMI TCP Connection(idle)" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dcac6000 nid=0x3d07 waiting on condition [0x0000700000e3d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007ac986018> (a java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)
    at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"JMX server connection timeout 30" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9b98800 nid=0x7c03 in Object.wait() [0x000070000278b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007aca93a68> (a [I)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.internal.ServerCommunicatorAdmin$Timeout.run(ServerCommunicatorAdmin.java:168)
    - locked <0x00000007aca93a68> (a [I)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dca5a800 nid=0x7a03 waiting on condition [0x0000700002688000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007ac98aad0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Connection(1)-10.10.2.22" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9b97800 nid=0x7803 runnable [0x0000700002584000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    - locked <0x00000007aca5c6f0> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:549)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.access$400(TCPTransport.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:684)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$1.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:681)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da900800 nid=0x3e0b runnable [0x0000700002482000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
    at sun.management.jmxremote.LocalRMIServerSocketFactory$1.accept(LocalRMIServerSocketFactory.java:52)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:399)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:371)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dd027800 nid=0x7503 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"ConsumerFetcherThread-SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerGroup_Relcys-MBP.relcy.com-1456260437755-207cd548-0-0" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dcaa4800 nid=0x7303 runnable [0x000070000227b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:200)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
    - locked <0x00000007ac68ff80> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000007ac68ff70> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000007ac68fe50> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream.read(SocketAdaptor.java:221)
    - locked <0x00000007ac68fa30> (a java.lang.Object)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    - locked <0x00000007ac690418> (a sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor$SocketInputStream)
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385)
    - locked <0x00000007ac690488> (a java.lang.Object)
    at kafka.utils.Utils$.read(Utils.scala:380)
    at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readFrom(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:54)
    at kafka.network.Receive$class.readCompletely(Transmission.scala:56)
    at kafka.network.BoundedByteBufferReceive.readCompletely(BoundedByteBufferReceive.scala:29)
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:111)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:71)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
    - locked <0x00000007ac566b10> (a java.lang.Object)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:112)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:111)
    at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
    at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:110)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:94)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:86)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)

"SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerGroup_Relcys-MBP.relcy.com-1456260437755-207cd548-leader-finder-thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9bb6800 nid=0x6907 waiting on condition [0x0000700001d6d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb2b5c0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:61)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)

"kafka-consumer-group-3" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da2ff800 nid=0x7103 waiting on condition [0x0000700002179000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb11540> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:63)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
    at com.relcy.analytics.kafka.consumer.SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.run(SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"kafka-consumer-group-2" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da2fe800 nid=0x6f03 waiting on condition [0x0000700002076000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb11d30> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:63)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
    at com.relcy.analytics.kafka.consumer.SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.run(SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"kafka-consumer-group-1" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da2fe000 nid=0x6d03 waiting on condition [0x0000700001f73000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb11a30> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:63)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
    at com.relcy.analytics.kafka.consumer.SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.run(SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"kafka-consumer-group-0" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da366000 nid=0x6b03 waiting on condition [0x0000700001e70000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb11bb0> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:63)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator.makeNext(ConsumerIterator.scala:33)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.maybeComputeNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.IteratorTemplate.hasNext(IteratorTemplate.scala:58)
    at com.relcy.analytics.kafka.consumer.SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.run(SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerHelper.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumerGroup_Relcys-MBP.relcy.com-1456260437755-207cd548_watcher_executor" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc990000 nid=0x6703 waiting on condition [0x0000700001c6a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb10080> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2176)
    at kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector$ZKRebalancerListener$$anon$1.run(ZookeeperConsumerConnector.scala:544)

"request-data-collector-0" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9b9a000 nid=0x6503 waiting on condition [0x0000700001b67000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb00440> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"kafka-consumer-scheduler-0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da2c9800 nid=0x6303 waiting on condition [0x0000700001a64000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb08510> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"main-EventThread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc9d2000 nid=0x6103 waiting on condition [0x0000700001961000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb20078> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$EventThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:491)

"main-SendThread(ec2-54-153-1-85.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2181)" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc86c800 nid=0x5f03 runnable [0x000070000185e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.kevent0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueArrayWrapper.poll(KQueueArrayWrapper.java:200)
    at sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl.doSelect(KQueueSelectorImpl.java:103)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)
    - locked <0x00000007aeb28100> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000007aeb28110> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x00000007aeb280b0> (a sun.nio.ch.KQueueSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:338)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)

"ZkClient-EventThread-13-ec2-54-153-1-85.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2181" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9b16000 nid=0x5e07 waiting on condition [0x000070000175b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb30070> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread.run(ZkEventThread.java:67)

"metrics-meter-tick-thread-2" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da19b800 nid=0x5703 waiting on condition [0x0000700001658000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb38068> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1085)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"metrics-meter-tick-thread-1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da19b000 nid=0x5503 waiting on condition [0x0000700001555000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007aeb38068> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2082)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1090)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9987800 nid=0x5303 runnable [0x0000700001452000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:530)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain$1.run(AppMain.java:90)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9886000 nid=0x4f03 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9865000 nid=0x4d03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1da007000 nid=0x4b03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9863000 nid=0x3a0f runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9851000 nid=0x3803 in Object.wait() [0x0000700000d3a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007aeb190f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007aeb190f0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9850800 nid=0x3603 in Object.wait() [0x0000700000c37000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007aeb189c8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007aeb189c8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9805000 nid=0x1703 waiting on condition [0x0000700000219000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.relcy.analytics.common.GenericKafkaConsumer.startConsumerServer(GenericKafkaConsumer.java:84)
    at com.relcy.analytics.kafka.consumer.SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumer.main(SessionBasedAnalyticsConsumer.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

"VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc80e800 nid=0x3403 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc806000 nid=0x2403 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc806800 nid=0x2603 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dd000000 nid=0x2803 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9817800 nid=0x2a03 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc807800 nid=0x2c03 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9818000 nid=0x2e03 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc808000 nid=0x3003 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1d9818800 nid=0x3203 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fd1dc821000 nid=0x5103 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 228
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the thread dump (use jstack <pid> to get it) of your program? See if some observations here (http://blog.jymob.com/blog/2014/12/01/top-and-java-threads/) help.

Comment: I read the blog post, but the keystrokes there did not work with `top` on Mac OS X. I attached a thread dump on my post.

Comment: Hard to say. Quick glance at thread dump suggests that most of the threads are executing the JDK/kafka code. I did not find any references to the CHM that you are using. So it seems to me that your code is not a culprit (yet). Also, what do you mean by: "My problem is that both programs, that work fine when run separately, appear to keep waiting."?

Comment: I myself feel that my question, although I elaborated in detail, is vague and too broad. I'll try to figure out more about the problem and either start another question or add more detail. Thank you.